# call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object error

Tags: php, mysqli

I just started to work with `bind_param` I have a simple HTML form to enter `Firstname Lastname` and `Age` into the database however when it is to insert I am getting the `call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` error which points to the following line: `$stmt->bind_param('ssi',$_POST['$fname'],$_POST['$lname'],$_POST['$age']);` below is the insert code: can I please have a few extra pair of eyes to aid

```
<?php

        $mysqli=@new mysqli('localhost','root','password','test');

        if($mysqli->connect_errno){
            die('Connect Error:'.$mysqli->connect_errno);
        }            

        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tester VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssi',$_POST['$fname'],$_POST['$lname'],$_POST['$age']);



        $stmt-> execute();

        printf("%d Row Inserted.\n\n",$stmt->affected_rows);

        $stmt->close();


        $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: **A:** => Remove all your `$` signs in your POST value binds.

Comment: @Fred-ii-I Removed them however Still getting the same error

Comment: *...I stand corrected;* partial "answer". Dan's your guy, he's got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssi',$_POST['$fname'],$_POST['$lname'],$_POST['$age']);
```

to:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssi',$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['age']);
```